# prove an integral reduction formula for $\cos^{m}x/\sin^{n}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

prove that:
$$\int {\cos^{m}x\over \sin^{n}x}dx = {\cos^{m-1}x\over (m-n)\sin^{n-1}x} + {m-1\over m-n}\int {\cos^{m-2}x\over \sin^{n}x}dx +C$$
What I did:

$$\int \cos^{m}x\sin^{-n}xdx= \int \cos x\cos^{m-1}x\sin^{-n}xdx$$
then I used integration by parts:
$u=\cos^{m-1}x$ $$du=-(m-1)\cos^{m-2}x\sin xdx$$ $$dv=\cos x\sin^{-n}xdx$$ and $$v={\sin^{-n+1}x\over-n+1}$$

hence:

$$\int {\cos^{m}x\over \sin^{n}x}dx= -{\cos^{m-1}x\over (n-1)\sin^{n-1}x} - {m-1\over n-1}\int {\cos^{m-2}x\over \sin^{n-2}x}dx$$

So I would like you to tell me what can I do to solve this and where is my mistake

Comment: Why don't you just take the derivative of the right-hand side and see if you get $\cos^m x / \sin^n x$?

Answer (score 3):

So far so good. When solving a problem like this, you have to look at what you should prove. Now you have got to: $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\cos^m x}{\sin^n x} dx = -\dfrac{\cos^{m-1}x}{(n-1)\sin^{n-1}x} - \dfrac{m-1}{n-1}\displaystyle\int \dfrac{\cos^{m-2} x}{\sin^{n-2} x} dx$.

Now basically, you have to manipulate $\dfrac{\cos^{m-2} x}{\sin^{n-2} x}$, to get $\dfrac{\cos^{m-2} x}{\sin^{n} x}$ as required by the problem. You can start by multiplying both numerator, and denominator by $\sin^2 x$, like this:

$$\begin{align}\displaystyle\int \dfrac{\cos^{m-2} x}{\sin^{n-2} x} dx &= \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\cos^{m-2} x\sin^2x}{\sin^{n} x} dx \\
&= \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\cos^{m-2} x(1-\cos^2x)}{\sin^{n} x}dx \\
&= \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\cos^{m-2} x-\cos^mx}{\sin^{n} x}dx
\end{align}$$

I think you can go from here, right? :)

This reminds me of a problem in a grade 12 math book in my country.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! :D I will finish it right now

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Suppose that $m>n$, then you have:
$$\int \cos^m(x) \sin^{-n}(x) dx = \int \cot^{n}(x) \cos^{m-n}(x) dx$$
For $n>m$ is analogous.

Comment: thanks a lot!! and one last question: is the formula above wrong?