# Trigonometric Integrals general approach

Tags: calculus, integration

Hello what is the idea of solving such an problems.$$\int \frac{\sin^m(x)\mathrm{d}x}{\cos^n(x)}$$.Having the formula doesn't help me understand the idea

Comment: Look at the standard trick - the tangent half-angle substitution. Sometimes called the Weierstrass substitution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: It will work but it is a lot of writing I know there is an easier method

Comment: You asked "What is the idea..." I didn't say it would be easy, but the general formula isn't going to be pretty. If $m$ is odd, there is a trivial replace of $\sin^2 x= 1-\cos^2 x$ and $\sin x\,dx = d(\cos x)$.

Comment: Thought I have seen this before ([see](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690799/prove-an-integral-reduction-formula-for-cosmx-sinnx)) with a shift of variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\int\frac{\sin^ax}{\cos^bx}d x$,
If a is odd then use $t=\cos x$.If a is even, and b is also even then use $t=\tan x$.If you have time and a is even then make it $\sin^{2p}x=(1-\cos^2x)^p$ in numerator and expand and divide and integrate.

Comment: Also we can make tg(x) on some random degree and always put csc(x) in d(x) ,what is left is either sin(x) or cos(x) and we always have formula to turn it to tg(x) ?

Comment: @Joesph what doyoumean by tg(x) ?tanx?

Comment: yes this is what i mean

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ is odd, by considering that $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$, we have to integrate $(\sin x)\cdot f(\cos x)$ where $f$ is a generalized polynomial (negative exponents are allowed). Given that $F$ is an easy-to-compute primitive of $f$, then $-F(\cos x)$ is a primitive for $(\sin x)\cdot f(\cos x)$.

If $m$ is even, by the same trick we can write the integrand function in terms of $\cos\theta$ only.

Then we can rely on integration by parts and induction, starting from:
$$\int\frac{dt}{\cos t}=\log\sqrt{\frac{\cos t+\sin t}{\cos t-\sin t}},\qquad \int\frac{dt}{\cos^2 t}=\tan t.$$